# Abstract class with Change Notifier

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to use a Change Notifier with my abstract class but do not think I have this set up correctly. Here is what I am doing:

```
abstract class Foo with ChangeNotifier {
  num get barValue;    
}

class FooUtil implements Foo {

  num _barNum = 0;

  num get barVale => _barNum;

  // assume this gets called every 10 seconds. 
  _someMethod(){
    _barNum++;
    notifyListeners();
  }

}

class Main() {

  Foo _foo = FooUtil();

  Main() {
   _foo.addListener(() {
        print(_foo.barValue);
     });
  }

}
```

I would like Main to be able to use the listener but this does not seem to work. Am I using the ChangeNotifier wrong in this instance? Is there a method that would work better?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a few overrides to conform to `ChangeNotififier`:

```
  @override
  void addListener(listener) {
    // TODO: implement addListener
  }

  @override
  // TODO: implement barValue
  num get barValue => throw UnimplementedError();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
  }

  @override
  // TODO: implement hasListeners
  bool get hasListeners => throw UnimplementedError();

  @override
  void notifyListeners() {
    // TODO: implement notifyListeners
  }

  @override
  void removeListener(listener) {
    // TODO: implement removeListener
  }
```

You will have to implement them before you can use the Class like that.